# I am not able to get error code line number in XCode debugger console, how to get line number?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am getting error code like follows

```
(gdb) continue
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb) continue
(gdb) continue
(gdb) continue
2011-11-08 17:31:53.156 OnContact[2849:207] *** -[CFString release]: message sent to             deallocated instance 0x4cf2eb0
(gdb) continue
Program received signal:  “SIGKILL”.
(gdb)
```

Can anybody help me finding out the line number where error had occured

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable NSZombie, that is designed to find such errors. See [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled)

Comment: I found that using NSZombie will disgard automatically releasing of memory, and you have to write code to release every variable. In my case I don't want to do all those work and just to findout the root variable of cause, do you have any other idea?